# Pass Func(Of TElement, TKey) as a function parameter

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I want to make a GetAllContacts method which takes a sort parameter of type Func(Of Contact, TKey) which is the same type that the OrderBy method for an IEnumerable(Of Contact) takes.  Here's my code:

```
    Public Function GetAllContacts(Of TKey)(ByVal sort As Func(Of Contact, TKey), ByVal sortDirection As SortDirection) As IEnumerable(Of Contact) Implements IContactRepository.GetAllContacts
        Select Case sortDirection
            Case sortDirection.Ascending
                Return ContactList.OrderBy(sort)
            Case sortDirection.Descending
                Return ContactList.OrderByDescending(sort)
        End Select
    End Function
```

When I call the GetAllContacts(Func(c) c.ContactID, SortDirection.Ascending), I get the error:

```
"Value of type 'System.Func(Of Contact, String)' cannot be converted to 'Integer'." on the first parameter
```

and

```
"Too many arguments to extension method 'Public Function ElementAtOrDefault(index As Integer) As Contact' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable'." on the second parameter.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where does `ElementAtOrDefault` come into this?

Comment: Well, according to the error message the function expects an Integer, not a Func(X,Y).

Comment: What is the type of ContactList?

Comment: @Rawling I don't know where it is coming from. I provided all of my code (besides the actual contact model).

Comment: @Meta-Knight What is ContactList? The GetAllContacts method returns an IEnumerable(Of Contact).

Comment: @just.another.programmer: If ContactList is an IEnumerable(Of Contact) then you shouldn't get any error in this code, or at least not the error you posted. Are you sure that the error is in that part of the code?

Comment: Is this really how you called it: `GetAllContacts(Func(c) c.ContactID, SortDirection.Ascending)`? When I try to pass a function that way I get an error :`Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this (net 4.0):

```
Public Function tst(a As String) As Integer
        Return a.Length
    End Function

    Public Function GetAllContacts(Of TKey)(ByVal sort As Func(Of String, TKey), ByVal sortDirection As DirectoryServices.SortDirection) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return {"a"}
    End Function
```

and this:

```
GetAllContacts(AddressOf tst, DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending)
GetAllContacts(Function(a As String) As Integer
                       Return a.Length
                   End Function, DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending)
GetAllContacts(Function(a) a.Length, DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending)
```

And I have no error.

Comment: I know it is not an answer but it ist too long for a comment. Hopefuly we get to answer if the above code is tested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of bad error messages.  I had a different signature in the interface than in the implementation.  As soon as I fixed the signature, the error went away.